# Copy-Item does not copy to correct target directory

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I'm trying to copy a directory structure with a PowerShell script. I wish to exclude a certain directory.

My directory structure looks like this:

```
C:\
└───murks
    ├───murks_source
    │   │   test1.txt
    │   │   test2.txt
    │   │
    │   ├───sub
    │   │       subtest1.txt
    │   │       subtest2.txt
    │   │       subtest3.txt
    │   │
    │   └───sub2
    │           sub2test.txt
    │
    └───murks_target
```

Now, when I run the script, it doesn't create the subdirectory "sub2" with the subordinate files. Instead, it copies all files (also those of the "sub2" subdirectory) directly into the murks_target_directory. I don't understand this behaviour, since the "Select -ExpandProperty FullName"-part looks good so far.

Any help or hints are highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

My script looks like this so far:

```
$rootFolderPath = 'C:\murks\murks_source'
$excludeDirectories = ("sub");

function Exclude-Directories
{
    process
    {
        $allowThrough = $true
        foreach ($directoryToExclude in $excludeDirectories)
        {
            $directoryText = "*\" + $directoryToExclude
            $childText = "*\" + $directoryToExclude + "\*"
            if (($_.FullName -Like $directoryText -And $_.PsIsContainer) `
                -Or $_.FullName -Like $childText)
            {
                $allowThrough = $false
                break
            }
        }

        if ($allowThrough)
        {
            return $_
        }
    }
}

Get-ChildItem $rootFolderPath -Recurse | Exclude-Directories | Select -ExpandProperty FullName | Copy-Item -Destination C:\murks\murks_target -Force
```

Comment: The problem is your flat -Destination, Copy-Item does exactly what you instruct it to do.

Comment: BTW don't reinvent the wheel, use `robocopy 'C:\murks\murks_source' 'C:\murks\murks_target' * /XD "sub" /S`

Comment: Hey dude. Maybe course through your options and choose an answer 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below custom function should do what you want:

```
function Copy-Path {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true, Position = 0)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType Container})]
        [string]$Source,

        [Parameter(Position = 1)]
        [string]$Destination,

        [string[]]$ExcludeFolders = $null,
        [switch]$IncludeEmptyFolders
    )
    $Source      = $Source.TrimEnd("\")
    $Destination = $Destination.TrimEnd("\")

    Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.PSIsContainer) {
            # it's a folder
            if ($ExcludeFolders.Count) {
                if ($ExcludeFolders -notcontains $_.Name -and $IncludeEmptyFolders) {
                    # create the destination folder, even if it is empty
                    $target = Join-Path -Path $Destination -ChildPath $_.FullName.Substring($Source.Length)
                    if (!(Test-Path $target -PathType Container)) {
                        Write-Verbose "Create folder $target"
                        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $target | Out-Null
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            # it's a file
            $copy = $true
            if ($ExcludeFolders.Count) {
                # get all subdirectories in the current file path as array
                $subs = $_.DirectoryName.Replace($Source,"").Trim("\").Split("\")
                # check each sub folder name against the $ExcludeFolders array
                foreach ($folderName in $subs) {
                    if ($ExcludeFolders -contains $folderName) { $copy = $false; break }
                }
            }

            if ($copy) {
                # create the destination folder if it does not exist yet
                $target = Join-Path -Path $Destination -ChildPath $_.DirectoryName.Substring($Source.Length)
                if (!(Test-Path $target -PathType Container)) {
                    Write-Verbose "Create folder $target"
                    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $target | Out-Null
                }
                Write-Verbose "Copy file $($_.FullName) to $target"
                $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $target -Force
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once in place, use it like this:

```
Copy-Path -Source 'C:\murks\murks_source' -Destination 'C:\murks\murks_target' -ExcludeFolders 'sub' -Verbose
```

Where parameter `-ExcludeFolders` can be an array of foldernames to skip.
Adding switch parameter `IncludeEmptyFolders` will also create empty folders in the destination. If left out, empty folders will not be copied.

Using your example file structure, the result is

> ```
> C:\murks\murks_target
> |   test1.txt
> |   test2.txt
> |
> \---sub2
>         sub2test.txt
> ```

Answer (score 1):

These can all be achieved with one-liners.

```
$source = 'C:\murks\murks_source'
$dest = 'C:\murks\murks_target'
```

Copy everything except the 'Sub' folders and their contents:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse | ? {$_.Name -notmatch 'sub'} | Copy-Item -Destination $dest
```

Preserve the folder structure including all files:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $source | Copy-Item -Destination $dest -Recurse -Container
```

Copy the folder structure but no files...

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $source | ? {$_.PSIsContainer} | Copy-Item -Destination $dest -Recurse -Exclude '*.*'
```

You can obviously combine example 1 and example 2 to preserve the folder/file structure and also exclude whatever directory you want by name, wildcard, etc.

Comment: A simple regex `'sub'` will also exclude sub2 xsub etc. A more complex regex might do `(?<=\\|^)sub(?=\\|$)` but the folders to exclude come from an array. Also the main problem is the flat destination.

Comment: Right. This is just an example. I am not even clear on what OP wants, other than to 'exclude a directory'. If that is one directory they know the name of, then plug it in. Otherwise use this as an example and tighten it up for your use.

Comment: This is what I helped solve for: "Instead, it copies all files (also those of the "sub2" subdirectory) directly into the murks_target_directory."

Comment: @LotPings solved the flat dest easily with -Container.

Comment: Yes, not recursing source and using `-Container` parameter with Copy-Item will do, just excluding `sub` is missing => `gci $source|? Name -ne 'sub'|Copy-Item -Dest $dest -Rec -Container`

Comment: Hi @LotPings . The exclusion isn’t missing...I recommended OP combine examples 1 and 2 to suit their needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've **almost** found an answer which would provide the functionallity which you disire.

```
$from = "C:\murks\murks_source"
$to = "C:\murks\murks_target"
$exclude = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\murks\murks_source\sub2\ -Depth 10
Copy-Item $from -Exclude $exclude -Destination $to -Recurse
```

It will ignore all files, except the folder structure.
The folder structure will be copied but empty.

Hope it helps.